# python multiprocessing Queue не выводит новые значения

Tags: python, python-2.x, очередь, multiprocessing

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, что делаю не так? Есть 2 функции. Первая использует функцию сбора данных и рузультат кладет в очередь. Вторая считывает из очереди и выводит в консоль. Ожидается, что данные будут меняться, но на деле первая запись, которая попала в очередь и будет выводиться. Как сделать так, что бы данные в очереди обновлялись? (Функция которая соберает данные - работает корректно и данные обновляются) Вот код:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

def put_data_queue(stopped, q):
    print"______START_DATA_PUT_TO_QUEUE_____"
    while not stopped.is_set():
        q.put(get_all_devices())
        stopped.wait(5)
    print"Stopping as you wish."


def my_consumer(stopped, q):
    print"_______START_READ_DATA_FROM_QUEUE____"
    while not stopped.is_set():
        if not q.empty():
            data = q.get()
            print data
        else:
            print"_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s"
            stopped.wait(2)

def get_all_devices():
    result = map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(INPUT))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(RELAY))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(AI))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(AO))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(SENSOR))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(LED))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(WATCHDOG))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(NEURON))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(UART))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(REGISTER))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(WIFI))
    result += map(lambda dev: dev.full(), Devices.by_int(LIGHT_CHANNEL))
    mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return result
```

И еще код, который запускает потоки:

```
q = Queue()
stopped = Event()
t1 = Process(target=put_data_queue, args=(stopped, q))
t2 = Process(target=my_consumer, args=(stopped, q))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Код, который останавливает потоки, находится в блоке кода основного приложения который реагирует на signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT и остановит потоки при нажатии на Ctrl+C.

```
stopped.set()
q.close()
q.join_thread()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Учел рекомендации в комментариях. Задача - два бесконечных цикла. Первый кладет изменяющиеся данные в очередь. Второй забирает данные из очереди, обрабатывает их и выводит в консоль. Если, я правильно понял то sentinel для python3, у меня python 2.7. Если заменить мою функцию по сбору данных на datetime.now(), то все работает корректно.

```
2018-03-30 14:30:06.608754
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
2018-03-30 14:30:11.610586
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
2018-03-30 14:30:16.611260
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
2018-03-30 14:30:21.611726
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
2018-03-30 14:30:26.612422
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
2018-03-30 14:30:31.612867
```

Значение времени меняется в очереди и забирается измененным. Если вернуть мою функцию - то вывод такой:

```
______START_DATA_PUT_TO_QUEUE_____
_______START_READ_DATA_FROM_QUEUE____
_____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
 _____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
 [{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
 [{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
 [{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
 _____WATING_DATA_FROM_QUEUE______2s
```

А устройств в списке не 2 а 24. И вывод устройств и количество одинаково. Я считаю, что если бы функция выполнялась то либо разное количество устройст было бы либо сами устройства менялись бы. А так получается что устройств два и они всегда одни и те же. Можно ли как проверить, что все данные с функции сборщика получены и доставлены в очередь?

Код на основе ответа выглядит так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import datetime as DT
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp


def producer(queue, stopped):
    while not stopped.wait(1):
        queue.put(get_all_devices())
    queue.put(None)   # put sentinel value (exit signal)


def consumer(queue):
    for item in iter(queue.get, None):
        mp.get_logger().info('item=%s', item)


mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stopped = mp.Event()
queue = mp.Queue()
mp.Process(target=producer, args=(queue, stopped)).start()
mp.Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,)).start()
```

Следующий код добавлен в функцию остановки главного приложения для завершения потока вместе с остановкой приложения:

```
stopped.set()
```

Строка mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG) добавлена в get_all_devices().
Вывод получаем такой:

```
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:63] eprom: UniPi Neuron S103 version: 1.0 serial: 0x1bb
[I 180403 09:07:00 evok:1630] Starting using config file /etc/evok.conf
[I 180403 09:07:00 evok:1631] Keys for write in redis_db 
['UART_15_2_01:ai|tank.1.pressure', 'software.evok.1']
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:75] YAML Definition loaded: S10x.yaml, type: 3, definition count 0
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:75] YAML Definition loaded: xS50.yaml, type: 3, definition count 1
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:75] YAML Definition loaded: xS10.yaml, type: 3, definition count 2
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:75] YAML Definition loaded: evok-alias.yaml, type: 2, definition count 0
[I 180403 09:07:00 evok:1695] HTTP server listening on port: 8080
[I 180403 09:07:00 prosolutions:147] Start work get_all_devices_decorator
No handlers could be found for logger "multiprocessing"
[I 180403 09:07:00 prosolutions:172] NO ALL GLOBAL DEV ID. Try one more cycle
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996066816
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996062720
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996058624
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996054528
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996050432
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996046336
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996042240
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 1996029952
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[D 180403 09:07:00 owclient:377] Entering 1wire loop
[I 180403 09:07:00 modbusclient_tornado:122] SPI client started
[DEBUG/Process-2] Queue._after_fork()
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[I 180403 09:07:00 modbusclient_rs485:333] UART client started
[I 180403 09:07:00 neuron:270] Reading the UART board on Modbus address 15
[DEBUG/Process-3] Queue._after_fork()
[INFO/Process-3] child process calling self.run()
[I 180403 09:07:00 neuron:159] Reading SPI boards
[I 180403 09:07:00 neuron:174] No board on SPI 2
[I 180403 09:07:00 neuron:174] No board on SPI 3
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:351] Alias loaded: <neuron.Relay object at 0x76041e70> al_lights_kitchen
[I 180403 09:07:00 config:351] Alias loaded: <neuron.Relay object at 0x76041450> al_lights_bedroom
[I 180403 09:07:01 config:351] Alias loaded: <neuron.Relay object at 0x76041e70> al_lights_kitchen
[I 180403 09:07:01 config:351] Alias loaded: <neuron.Relay object at 0x76041450> al_lights_bedroom
[I 180403 09:07:01 prosolutions:147] Start work get_all_devices_decorator
[INFO/MainProcess] ndevices=24
[INFO/MainProcess] ndevices=24
[I 180403 09:07:01 prosolutions:169] Key UART_15_2_01:ai founded in devices
[I 180403 09:07:01 prosolutions:120] No option 'set_mode' in section: 'NEURON_1'
[I 180403 09:07:01 prosolutions:179] Ended work get_all_devices_decorator
[I 180403 09:07:01 prosolutions:138] User switch AI-mode for UART_15_2_01 to Current
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[DEBUG/Process-2] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Process-2] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Process-2] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/Process-2] ... done self._thread.start()
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2
[INFO/Process-3] item=[{'ver2': '1.0', 'dev': 'neuron', 'glob_dev_id': 1, 'sn': 443, 'circuit': '1', 'model': 'S103', 'board_count': 0}, {'uart_circuit': 'None', 'version_registers': [], 'dev': 'neuron', 'circuit': 'UART_15_2', 'model': 'xS50', 'uart_port': '/dev/extcomm/0/0'}]
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[I 180403 09:07:07 evok:1775] Shutting down
```

После добавления логгера в функцию  get_all_devices() видно, что [INFO/MainProcess] ndevices=24 получаем 24 устрйоства а в дополнительном потоке потоке получаем [INFO/Process-2] ndevices=2   - 2 устройства. Получается, что при старте потока get_all_devices() как то сохраняет состояние на момент инициализации устройств, когда их два. И потом не меняет своего вывода, когда устройств становится больше.

Вот простой код который имитирует мою проблему file_1:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
from file_2 import *


def producer(queue, stopped):
    while not stopped.wait(1):
        queue.put(data_list)
    queue.put(None)   # put sentinel value (exit signal)


def consumer(queue):
    for item in iter(queue.get, None):
        mp.get_logger().info('item=%s', item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    print data_list
    data_creator(100)
    stopped = mp.Event()
    queue = mp.Queue()
    print data_list
    mp.Process(target=producer, args=(queue, stopped)).start()
    mp.Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,)).start()
    data_creator(200)
    raw_input('Press <Enter> to exit.')
    print data_list
    stopped.set()
```

file_2:

```
data_list = [100]


def data_creator(data):
    data_list.append(data + 10)
```

Вывод:

```
[100]
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 176
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 184
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 192
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 196
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 200
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 408
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 412
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[100, 110]
Press <Enter> to exit.[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 12
[[DEBUG/Process-2] recreated blocker with handle 24
DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 20
[[DEBUG/Process-2] recreated blocker with handle 32
DEBUG/Process-1] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/Process-2] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 36
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 40
[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 44
[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 48
[DEBUG/Process-1] recreated blocker with handle 52
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/Process-1] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Process-1] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Process-1] ... done self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Process-1] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]
[INFO/Process-2] item=[100]

[100, 110, 210]
[[[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Могу ли я получить список из трех элементов, а не из одного стартового?

Comment: у вас `stopped.set()` сразу вызывается. Чего вы ожидали получить? Попробуйте *минимальный* пример  кода создать. К примеру, заменитеc `get_all_devices()` на `datetime.now()`. stopped в `my_consumer()` не нужно передавать, если вы хотите все элементы очереди забрать, вместо этого добавьте sentinel в producer, когда он выходит. Приведите явно вывод, который получаете и явно словами опишите какой вместо этого вывод хотели бы (multiprocessing logger используйте). [mcve]

Comment: если проблема в `get_all_devices()` функции, то прямо в этой функции и сравнивайте новые результаты, с результатами прошлых вызовов.

Comment: Проблема не в get_all_devices(). Функция собирает данные корректо. Проблема в том, что после попадания в put_data_queue() функция get_all_devices() не меняет выдаваемого значения  или значении функции как-то сохраняется. Я вставлял принты в  get_all_devices() - они все отображаются, то есть вызов функции происходит в цикле но значение почему-то не меняется.

Comment: вы же сами сказали: c `datetime.now()` всё работает. Возьмите код из моего ответа и внесите **минимальные** изменения, до тех пор пока вы его не сломаете или пока он с `get_all_devices()`  у вас не заработает: получив *полный* *минимальный* пример с описание чем его вывод отличается от желаемого, опубликуйте его в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ваш код работает с datetime.now(). Я заменил DT.datetime.now() на  get_all_devices() и получил список из 2-х устройств. Функция get_all_devices() возвращает список из 24-х устройств. Пример вывода  я  опубликовал в вопросе выше. Могу опубликовать весь вывод логгера с функцией get_all_devices()

Comment: добавьте в конце `get_all_devices()`: `mp.get_logger().info('ndevices=%s', len(result))`. Включите в вопрос полный код (на основе моего ответа) и соответствующий вывод.

Comment: добавил информацию. Посмотрите, может есть идеи как это решить?

Comment: слова "полный код" означают точный код, который вы запускали как есть без упущений, упрощений, итд.

Comment: Добавить полный код - это задача близкая к невозможной. Попробую объяснить - есть приложение называется EVOK. Вот его код https://github.com/UniPiTechnology/evok. Там я создал свой файл с  кодом функций для потоков. А запускаю эти потоки в секции main файла evok.py. В коде ЕВОК я нашел код для получения устройств и сделал из него функцию get_all_devices() и ее использую.

Comment: мой код в ответе демонстрирует, что проблема в коде, который не показан. Нечего обсуждать.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы  jfs частично ответили на мою проблему в другом вопросе. Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753198/python-hashlib-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-multiprocessing?rq=1 Вы написали "multiprocessing.Process создаёт отдельный системный процесс — со своим отдельным адресным пространством. Изменение переменных в одном процессе никак не влияет на другой процесс" Это поведение очень похоже на мою ситуацию. В момент инициализации потока произошло создание отдельного адресного пространства и get_all_devices() получила 2 устройства. И их выдает.

Comment: С течением времени в основном потоке get_all_devices() получает 24 устройства, но на второй поток это не влияет, там по прежнему 2 устройства. Вариант для решения проблемы - использовать threads? Или как-то через Manager классы  передавать данные из основного процесса во вторичный?

Comment: в конце ответа там упомянута явно Queue как одно из решений. Вы *уже* используете Queue. Ещё раз: проблема в коде, который не показан. Если вам мало примера с datetime, то руками создайте список строк и с помощью очереди перешлите в другой процесс, убедившись что целиком доходит. Затем список устройств попробуйте в байты *руками* превратить в одном процессе, отослать эти байты в другой, а там восстановить из байт.

Comment: [ответ на `data_list` пример здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/779674/23044) -- это другая проблема (вы утверждаете, что данные теряются при отсылки с одного конца очереди и получении на другом. В `data_list` примере, что вы в очередь положили, то на другом конце и получите). Я имел в виду, чтобы  вы **внутри** функции с очередью создали бы список.

Comment: Стоит ещё иметь в виду [следующее объяснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804982/23044)

Comment: Видимо я недостаточно четко объяснял свою проблему. Темы, что вы указали - это то что нужно. Спасибо за ваше терпение и время.

Comment: jfs если Вас не затруднит подскажите решение для задачи, примерно такой как в последнем моем примере. Условия задачи - есть список. Список постоянно пополняется элементами(или меняется значение элементов) в одном процессе. Нужно постоянно получать этот изменяемый список в другом процессе. Использовать multiprocessing. Я попробовал с глобальными переменными решить вопрос последнего примера. Не получилось. У Process нет параметра initializer как у Pool.  Могу создать новый вопрос с примером кода.

Comment: в вашем вопросе как минимум пара неверных предположений, объяснение к одному из них я уже озвучивал. Попробуйте на более мелкие вопросы разбить для начала (ответ про аналог initializer для Process крайне простой—хотя он никак с более сложной проблемой не поможет, по причине описанной по ссылкам выше). Можно ещё раз повторить в одном из новых вопросов почему обновления *после* отправки не видны в другом процессе. Для фиксированных размеров и Си типов можно общую память использовать (не рекомендуется), лучше (понятнее, универсальнее) явно пересылать требуемые изменения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример producer-consumer системы: один процесс генерирует значения и кладёт их в очередь, другой их потребляет, ожидая сигнала выйти:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import datetime as DT
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp


def producer(queue, stopped):
    while not stopped.wait(1):
        queue.put(DT.datetime.now())
    queue.put(None)   # put sentinel value (exit signal)


def consumer(queue):
    for item in iter(queue.get, None):
        mp.get_logger().info('item=%s', item)


mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stopped = mp.Event()
queue = mp.Queue()
mp.Process(target=producer, args=(queue, stopped)).start()
mp.Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,)).start()
raw_input('Press <Enter> to exit.')
stopped.set()
```